# Plot list of lists (which different length) in a plot in python

Tags: python, numpy, plot

I have a list of lists, each of these internal lists has a different length, and I would like to show them in a graph.

They would look like this:

```
data = [[4,3,4],[2,3],[5,6,4,5]]
```

for each of these, I would like to plot them against there index (x-axis), so for instance, for the first list: (0,4),(1,3),(2,4)

If my lists would have been the same length, I would have converted them to a numpy array and just plotted them:

```
data_np = np.vstack(data)
plot_data_np = np.transpose(data_np)
plt.plot(plot_data_np)
```

However, there is this length issue... In a hopeful attempt I tried:

```
plt.plot(data)
```

But alas.

Comment: If you change it to `data = [[4,3,4,0],[2,3,0,0],[5,6,4,5]]`, does the result look right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about just doing

```
data = [[4,3,4],[2,3],[5,6,4,5]]
for d in data:
    plt.plot(d)
```

?

Comment: Too easy... Thanks!